# jQuery: Mute all sounds if sound button is turned off

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heeey, I tried to code a sound control function. Someone helped me doing it and now I have a last problem: How is it possible to mute the click buttons as well if the sound control button is turned off? The buttons should still work because there should be links on them later.

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var background_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  background_sound.src = "https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/airport-gate-1.mp3";
  background_sound.volume = 0.1;
  background_sound.autoPlay = true;
  background_sound.loop = true;
  background_sound.controls = true;
  background_sound.play();


  var click_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  click_sound.src = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3";
  click_sound.volume = 0.1;
  click_sound.autoPlay = false;
  click_sound.preLoad = true;
  click_sound.controls = true;


  $(".click_sound").click(function() {
    click_sound.currentTime = 0;
    click_sound.play();
  });

  $(".sound_control").click(function() {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (background_sound.currentTime) {
      background_sound.currentTime = 0;
      background_sound.pause();
    } else {
      background_sound.play();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.on_off:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sound_control">Sound <span class="on_off">on</span><span class="on_off">off</span></button>

<button class="click_sound">Button One</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Two</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Three</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Four</button>
```

Would be very happy if someone can help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".sound_control").click(function () {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (background_sound.currentTime) {
      background_sound.currentTime = 0;
      background_sound.pause();
      toggleButtons(false)
    } else {
      background_sound.play();
      toggleButtons(true)
    }
  });
  function toggleButtons (isOpen) {
    if(isOpen)
    $(".click_sound").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled")
    else
    $(".click_sound").attr("disabled", "disabled")
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var background_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  background_sound.src =
    "https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/airport-gate-1.mp3";
  background_sound.volume = 0.1;
  background_sound.autoPlay = true;
  background_sound.loop = true;
  background_sound.controls = true;
  background_sound.play();

  var click_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  click_sound.src =
    "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3";
  click_sound.volume = 0.1;
  click_sound.autoPlay = false;
  click_sound.preLoad = true;
  click_sound.controls = true;

  const onButtonClick = function () {
    click_sound.currentTime = 0;
    click_sound.play();
  };
  $(".click_sound").click(onButtonClick);

  $(".sound_control").click(function () {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (background_sound.currentTime) {
      background_sound.currentTime = 0;
      background_sound.pause();
      toggleButtons(false);
    } else {
      background_sound.play();
      toggleButtons(true);
    }
  });
  function toggleButtons(isOpen) {
    if (isOpen) {
      $(".click_sound")
        .on("click", onButtonClick);
    } else {
      $(".click_sound").off("click");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.on_off:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button class="sound_control">Sound <span class="on_off">on</span><span class="on_off">off</span></button>
    
    <button class="click_sound">Button One</button>
    <button class="click_sound">Button Two</button>
    <button class="click_sound">Button Three</button>
    <button class="click_sound">Button Four</button>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Hmm ... the buttons should still work. There should be links on them later. But the sound should be off.

Comment: Updated solution